Checkbox group filter how to put it in where clause
I have a interactive report with some items that are used as a filter in this report, like text field, select list etc.
Now i have a checkbox group but I don't know how to put the input in the where clause of my query.
and (emp.status = :p77_status or :p77_status is null)
this one is not working
because at page load, all the checkboxes are deselected, yet my query shows as if all checkboxes were selected.

I presume that's because checkbox's default value probably isn't NULL, but 'N' (as "No", "Not selected") for default settings, or 0 (zero) if you changed it that way, or some other value.
Try to modify where clause to e.g.
and (emp.status = :p77_status or :p77_status = 'N')

or
and (emp.status = :p77_status or nvl(:p77_status, 'N') = 'N')

Basically, check what's checkbox item set to (when not selected).
[EDIT]
As it is a checkbox group, then: values you check are stored as colon-separated values, for example 1:4:5. In that case, split them into rows and use such a subquery in where clause:
where emp_status in  (select regexp_substr(:P77_STATUS, '[^:]+', 1, level)
                          from dual
                          connect by level <= regexp_count(:P77_STATUS, ':') + 1
                         );     


And how does this work if i want to select multiple checkboxes? Because then it says:
'invalid number'

Include each of them into the WHERE clause.

Sorry, how would that work exactly? :p77_status can be a number from 1 to 5 so how can I say that :p77_status can be 1?
like this?
and (:p77_status = 1 or :p77_status = 'N')
and (:p77_status = 2 or :p77_status = 'N')
etc?

Isn't P77_STATUS a checkbox item? I though it is. And - if it really is - a checkbox can have only two values: checked and not checked. How can it contain values from 1 to 5?

Because I use it as a filter for different values. eg job type: a checkbox for president, a checkbox for manager, a checkbox for analyst, a checkbox for clerk, a checkbox for salesman. So you can select multiple checkboxes

Have a look at edited answer, please.

It's possible to check the current value of the page item without actually submitting the page. For that, open the browsers development console and use one of the following notations to print out the value of the page item
$v('P77_STATUS')
apex.item('P77_STATUS').getValue()
apex.items.P77_STATUS.getValue()

In this screenshot I'm using the newest notation to get the current value for page item P37_TOGGLE_SCOTT

The difference between those notations is the version they were introduced.  The "$v" notation has been around for a very long time, apex.item() was introduced a lot later and apex.items.PAGE_ITEM is the most modern notation. But they all work and all return the same value.
Have a play with this in your page, the dev console can be a useful tool in apex development. The apex javascript apis are documented here. Once you know what the value is when on and off you can adjust the where clause accordingly.
